# Facebook Rest API, "restfb", doesn't allow me to use a method that exists in the library

Tags: eclipse, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb, facebook-rest-api

I am trying to get used with Facebook API, restfb, but I have an annoying problem that is keep persisting.
The code looks as follows:

```
FacebookClient fc = new DefaultFacebookClient(TOKEN, Version.VERSION_2_0);
User user = fc.fetchObject("me", User.class);
System.out.println(user.getName());
```

The method "fetchObject" exists in DefaultFacebookClient as follows:

```
public <T> T fetchObject(String object, Class<T> objectType, Parameter... parameters)
```

But Eclipse throws a compiling error saying:

```
The method fetchObject(String, Class, Parameter[]) in the type FacebookClient is not applicable for the arguments (String, Class<T>)
```

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: It seems that I managed to make it working. I just had to chang the Eclipse JRE version for my project. If anyone has any idea why a smaller JRE smaller version wasn't working feel free to say.

Comment: Can you provide the concrete version numbers?